# How to extend style object

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a short way to populate some css elements. 
I want a fast way to set style properties  of an element.

I can do (for example) :

```
Element.prototype.set_box = function  (left, top, width, height) 
   { this.style.left = left+"px";    this.style.top=top+"px";
     this.style.width  = width+"px"; this.style.height = height+"px";         
   }

 obj = getElementById(id_name);
 obj.set_box (10,20,300,200);
```

I'd want not must to write code to access to the style object, but access to the style object itself, something like this:

```
Element.style.prototype.set_box = function  (left, top, width, height) 
   { this.left = left+"px";    this.top=top+"px";
     this.width  = width+"px"; this.height = height+"px";         
   }
```

or

```
 Style.prototype.set_box = function  (left, top, width, height) 
   { this.left = left+"px";    this.top=top+"px";
     this.width  = width+"px"; this.height = height+"px";         
   }
```

But is not possible. I have a warning  "undefined....". 
Any idea ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct prototype to extend is:

```
CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.set_box = function...
```

In general, to find this out, run something like this in your console:

```
[a known instance of the object].constructor
```

For example:

```
document.body.style.constructor
```